# How can I sync ebooks to my iPad without removing the existing ones?

Tags: ipad, books, ebook

I have an iPad 3 ("iPad 2 Retina") that I use basically just as an e-reader now.  It is still running iOS 6.1 and has a collection of eBooks on it.

I want to sync a new ebook over to it from my Macbook Pro running Catalina, however if I tick the Sync box in Finder I'm asked if I want to remove all the books on the iPad currently.  Clearly I do NOT want to do this!

How can I add an eBook to my iPad from my Mac without removing anything that's currently on it?

Comment: What reader are you using? Does it have OPDS, Dropbox etc?

Comment: I'm using iBooks so no.

Comment: Then I think you're going to need something like iMazing to get the books back onto the Mac first, then iTunes can sync 'properly'. It's not something i've ever tried . I don't use iBooks, sorry. I use Marvin, which can freely move books either way.

Comment: How would I get any other app given that the old iPad can no longer connect to the iTunes Store?

Comment: That question implies you didn't even google the word iMazing.

Comment: Well of course I didn't... I expect it's an app in the app store which I cannot access so... why would I google it?  But since you now have made such a point about it I will do so.  But it's not like my iPad is jailbroken or anything.

Comment: Oh it's a MAC app, I thought you were talking about an iPad reader app.  I had no desire to get books "onto the mac first" so disregarded that part.  iMazing has done the trick, thank you.